# Xephyr with KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde

I am hoping someone can help me with this. I am using KDE4, trying to run a Xephyr session that will load KDM and allow me to login another desktop user in a window of my host KDE session. I have Xephyr installed, and I am using the command:

Xephyr -ac -screen 1440x900 -br -reset -terminate -name "Xephyr" 2> /dev/null :2 &
export DISPLAY=:2.0

From there, I can run applications in the window, like Chrome or whatever. But I have not been able to run KDM or KDE.

I tried "dbus-launch /usr/bin/startkde &" but then the system says : $DISPLAY is not set or cannot connect to the X server.

If I try and just "startx" the Xephyr window crashes. Oh I did allow anybody to run an X session and I set XDMCP to true in KDM too btw. I have yet to find anything online for help :(

Comment: The Xaccess setting ? Really old: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?26343-SOLVED-Simple-How-To-Attached-Screenshot-of-Login-Screen-XDMCP&p=102628&viewfull=1#post102628 . The Xaccess path with the KDE4 is /etc/kde4/kdm/Xaccess

Answer (score 0):

**At here**

Using the: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?26343-SOLVED-Simple-How-To-Attached-Screenshot-of-Login-Screen-XDMCP&p=102628&viewfull=1#post102628 as guide.

1) /etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc

```
[Xdmcp]
Enable=true
```

2) /etc/kde4/kdm/Xaccess

```
*                   #any host can get a login window
```

3) Konsole

```
Xephyr :1 -query 127.0.0.1 -screen 800x600
```

Seems to work.

[image]